# npx react-native init MainApp Giving error (code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',) . What's the isue here

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I got this error while running the above command **(npx react-native init MainApp)**
I have installed the latest version of node and npm. I am not sure why this error is reflected.
Tried clearing the cache changing the **node version to 17** but no luck. I am new to this react native.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
      throw err;
      ^
    
    Error: Cannot find module './error'
    Require stack:
    - C:\Users\priye\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@hapi\hoek\lib\assert.js
    - C:\Users\priye\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@hapi\topo\lib\index.js
    - C:\Users\priye\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\joi\lib\types\keys.js
    - C:\Users\priye\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\joi\lib\types\function.js
    - C:\Users\priye\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\joi\lib\index.js
    - C:\Users\priye\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\schema.js
    - C:\Users\priye\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\readConfigFromDisk.js
    - C:\Users\priye\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\index.js
    - C:\Users\priye\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\install\install.js
    - C:\Users\priye\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\index.js
    - C:\Users\priye\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js
    - C:\Users\priye\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
        at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\priye\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@hapi\hoek\lib\assert.js:3:21)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
        at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
      code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
      requireStack: [
        'C:\\Users\\priye\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@hapi\\hoek\\lib\\assert.js',
        'C:\\Users\\priye\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@hapi\\topo\\lib\\index.js',
        'C:\\Users\\priye\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\node_modules\\joi\\lib\\types\\keys.js',
        'C:\\Users\\priye\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\node_modules\\joi\\lib\\types\\function.js',
        'C:\\Users\\priye\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\node_modules\\joi\\lib\\index.js',
        'C:\\Users\\priye\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\build\\tools\\config\\schema.js',
        'C:\\Users\\priye\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\build\\tools\\config\\readConfigFromDisk.js',
        'C:\\Users\\priye\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\build\\tools\\config\\index.js',
        'C:\\Users\\priye\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\build\\commands\\install\\install.js',
        'C:\\Users\\priye\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\build\\commands\\index.js',
        'C:\\Users\\priye\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\build\\index.js',
        'C:\\Users\\priye\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\build\\bin.js'
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I myself resolved the issue. I deleted the npm-cache folder from the AppData folder and it worked :). Thanks[image]